# R - extract lines from matrix that meet given condition?

Tags: r, rows, indices

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    1    1
[3,]    0    1    0
[4,]    0    0    1
[5,]    1    0    0
```

Given a matrix like that above - what is an efficient way to iterate over the matrix, selecting rows for which the first element is 1 and all other elements are 0, such that

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3]    
[1,]    1    0    0    
[2,]    1    0    0
```

is returned?

Thanks,
D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recreate the data:

```
a <- array(c(1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0), dim=c(5,3))
```

Now create a vector that equals the condition.

```
cond <- c(1, 0, 0)
```

Next, an `apply` statement wrapped in a call to `which` will tell you which rows match your condition

```
which(apply(a, 1, function(x)all(x==cond)))
1] 1 5
```

Finally, to extract the rows where this condition is met:

```
x <- which(apply(a, 1, function(x)all(x==cond)))
a[x, ]


     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0
```

The resulting array doesn't contain much information.  Perhaps you wanted to know how many rows match the condition?

```
length(x)
[1] 2
```

---

To answer the follow-on question.  How to create a condition vector when the array is large?

Well, one way is as follows.  Let's say you have an array of 100 columns wide, so you need a vector of 100 in length, and you want the third element to be a 1:

```
cond <- rep(0, 100)
cond[3] <- 1
cond
  [1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [38] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [75] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: I like this solution, but defining the conditions beforehand is problematic. Can the code be modified so that the condition does not have to be created as a vector beforehand? Suppose I want all rows where the 2nd column ==1 and all other columns==0, and perhaps I want rows where the 3rd column==1, etc. Considering that the matrix is large (~1000x1000) it is not feasible to generate all possible conditions. Thanks, D ;-)